# Allegro5 and MS Visual Studio 2010

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, installation, allegro5

recently I treid to add Allegro5 library to Visual Studio 2010. I visited allegro.cc and downloaded package called: allegro-5.0.4-msvc-10.0 (following the name, I think it's correct one) and after extracxtion, and I copied:

```
/bin to C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\bin
/include to C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\include
/lib to C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\lib

Allegro's dlls to C:\Windows\System32

I also added "alld.lib" in project -> properties -> linker -> input
```

And when I tried to use Allegro in my project, I could included Allegro's headers but it's an error when I tried to type something simple like:

```
#include <allegro5\allegro.h>

int main()
{
    allegro_init();

    return 0;
}
```

It generates an error (red underline in typing mode) : undefinded identifier "allegro_init".
Would anyone give me a tip what might be wrong in this configuration?
I'll be very glad for all hints and solutions. 
Greetings,

Comment: have you tried compiling it? Does it give any errors?

Comment: I wish people would stop copying libraries into VS's directories. If you want to put libraries in a centralized place, then create a centralized place and just reference those locations from Visual Studio.

Comment: Perhaps [this](http://wiki.allegro.cc/index.php?title=Windows,_Visual_Studio_2010_and_Allegro_5) would help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please see the documentation on the wiki for [Allegro 5 and Visual Studio 2010](http://wiki.allegro.cc/index.php?title=Windows,_Visual_Studio_2010_and_Allegro_5). Especially note the bit about not modifying system folders like you have already done.

Anyway, the problem here is that you are trying to write Allegro 4 code but you've installed Allegro 5. The two are not compatible. Allegro 5 is completely rewritten and designed for modern hardware. The correct equivalent program is:

```
#include <allegro5/allegro.h>

int main(int argc, const char *argv[])
{
  al_init();
  return 0;
}
```

Also, you are linking with Allegro 4, judging by the name of the file. The libraries as included in the binary package are [described here](http://www.allegro.cc/manual/5/install/windows.html). There are many different versions included for debugging, for static run times, etc. The most direct equivalent for `alld.lib` is `allegro-5.0.4-monolith-md-debug.lib`.

You can find the manual here: http://www.allegro.cc/manual/5/

Answer (score 1):

Well your big problem is, I'd guess, that you aren't actually telling the linker how to load the DLL.

You could do it manually using [LoadLibrary](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684175%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and [GetProcAddress](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683212%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

However most of the time when you build a DLL you'll find you get a library which handles all the above dynamic linking for you.  As a result you'll find its much easier to just add that lib to the linker "inputs".